# Script to check unassigned tickets in jira?(java, python or another)

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

I want to check unassigned tickets in jira using java,python or any other script.

Comment: JQL: assignee is empty

Answer (score 0):

Using jira-python we first search for all the possible issues, then we check if the assignee field is None, thus nobody assigned.

```
# search_issues can only return 1000 issues, so if there are more we have to search again, thus startAt=count
issues = []
while True:
    tmp_issues = jira_connection.search_issues('', startAt=count, maxResults=count + 999)
    if len(tmp_issues) == 0:
        # Since Python does not offer do-while, we have to break here.
        break
    issues.extend(tmp_issues)
    count += 999

not_assigned = []
for i in issues:
    if i.fields.assignee is None:
        not_assigned.add(i)
```